# Why is the 2nd thread not starting?

Tags: python

This code doesn't give me the output I expect. Something must be wrong, but I cannot understand what it could be.

```
import thread
import time

def func1(threadName, sleepTime):
    while 1 < 2:
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        print "%s" % (threadName)

def func2(threadName, sleepTime):
    while 1 < 2:
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        print "%s" % (threadName)


try:
    thread.start_new_thread(func1("slow" , 5))
    thread.start_new_thread(func2("fast" , 1))
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

The output I expect is something like:

```
fast
fast
fast
fast
slow
fast
```

and so on, but only the 1st thread seems to be starting. I implemented the "try and except" block later to see if there's an error somewhere but no error!

Comment: It looks like the functions are being called before the threads are started.

Comment: Take the time to format and spell check your question.  If you don't put any effort into your question, how can you expect us to put effort into answering it?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the functions are being called before the threads are started.  I'm not very familiar with Python, but try:

```
thread.start_new_thread(func1, ("slow" , 5))
thread.start_new_thread(func2, ("fast" , 1))
```

Notice the comma after the function name - you pass in the function as one argument, and a tuple of the argument parameters as a separate argument.  This lets `start_new_thread` call your function when the new thread is ready.

Comment: This is precisely what's going on.